# Escaping quotes in a javascript object generated from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I feel like this must surely be a duplicate of an oft-answered question, but I cannot find an answer that addresses my particular issue.

I am loading data from MySQL via PHP, including some strings and a JSON-encoded string. This data may contain special characters, entered by the user.

I then combine this data into a PHP array, then `json_encode` it and read it into javascript using `JSON.parse`.

My issue is that an apostrophe in any of these strings will interrupt the javascript, preventing the `JSON.parse` from completing.

I think there are three ways to solve this:

1. Do some sort of encoding on the user-entered data before it gets saved to the database
2. Escape the special characters when loading from the MySQL (using `htmlspecialchars()` or similar), though this will be difficult when loading data that's stored as a JSON string (I suppose I could decode it, then loop through and escape special characters in each element, then re-encode it).
3. Escape the special characters in javascript, somehow. But I don't know how I'd do this.

I would have to say that special character encoding is probably the single-most frustrating aspect of web development, as it causes me so many unexpected errors and I struggle to understand the different functions and when they should be used.

**EDIT:**

```
var feedback = JSON.parse('{"721103":[{"sessionid":"45","feedback":{"praise":["","",""],"development":["","",""]}},{"sessionid":"46","feedback":{"praise":["Test","Test's",""],"development":["","",""]}}') ;
```

The apostrophe in `Test's` breaks the javascript

Comment: Can you include `JSON` response from `php` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 See edit

Comment: You could search for `'` inside the JSON string and replace it with `\'`.

Comment: can you share the php array that you are encoding

Comment: Why do you need `JSON.parse('`…`');`? Can’t you just use the output object as it is?

Comment: @Xufox If I don't use JSON.parse, surely I'll just be left with a string instead of a javascript object/array

Comment: @Rob Depends on whether the single quotes `'` are part of your PHP output or not. I assume, they aren’t.

Comment: @Xufox The overall object is a PHP array assembled in my code. Within that the 'feedback' bits are JSON encoded strings that are retrieved from the database.

Comment: `var sessions = JSON.parse(`[{"id":"53","name":"Te\"t'","timestamp":"2017-10-31 03:04:56"}]`) ;`
Note the use of \`\` quotes to prevent the single quotes interfering, and that the double quote has been automatically escaped when it was submitted by AJAX. However, I still receive this error:
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 24 of the JSON data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempts to edit @kmoser's answer with the actual solution that worked were rejected in peer review, so here's what worked. All credit to @kmoser:

`$json_feedback = preg_replace( preg_quote('/\u/'), '\\\\\\\\u', json_encode( $feedback, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT ) );`

It works by replacing singles and double quotes with hex strings when the data is retrieved from the MySQL database. For reasons I don't understand, that still broke the javascript, so I then did a `preg_replace` to put an additional backslash before the escaped code.

Notice how many backslashes I had to put in to persuade the preg_replace to put in the additional backslash to prevent the javascript breaking. I may be able to get away with fewer backslashes, the number that appears here is mostly out of sheer frustration with this silly issue!

Answer (score 3):

This should prevent your javascript from breaking:

```
var feedback = JSON.parse(`{"721103":[{"sessionid":"45","feedback":{"praise":["","",""],"development":["","",""]}},{"sessionid":"46","feedback":{"praise":["Test","Test's",""],"development":["","",""]}}]}`) ;
```

It uses ``, instead of ''. They work the same, but won't be affecting eachother.

I also corrected your json syntax error.

Comment: it is still invalid json..you can check json if it's valid or not in jsonlint.com

Comment: @DhavalChheda Ye, saw it. I edited it to have a valid JSON. Seems like op has 2 problems in his code.

Comment: @ubj2216 Thanks for that. The invalid json is because I deleted too much when I pasted it into SO: the real code is fine.

Comment: @ubj2216 I'll give the `` a try. I guess it will work unless, and this is unlikely, a user enters a ` into the form

Answer (score 2):

Don't munge user data before storing in the DB. You can munge it all you want after retrieving it.

I assume you're using PHP's [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to produce the JSON-encoded string, in which case you can use the `JSON_HEX_APOS` option to encode apostrophes as `\u0027`, e.g.:

```
json_encode( $a, JSON_HEX_APOS )
```

Where `$a` is your PHP array. This should produce a JSON string devoid of actual apostrophes, which you can surround with apostrophes to create a Javascript string:

```
echo "var feedback = JSON.parse('" . json_encode( $a, JSON_HEX_APOS ) . "')";
```

Comment: This seems like it should be the perfect solution, but I implement it and still get an error from a seemingly valid JSON string:
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 20 of the JSON data`

Comment: The string being: `var praise = [{"comment":"Te\u0027sT\"t","times_selected":"1","id":"31"},{"comment":"","times_selected":"1","id":"32"},{"comment":"","times_selected":"1","id":"33"}] `

Comment: Try ``json_encode( $a, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT )``

Comment: Thank you. I just did that, and it has now turned the string into: `[{"comment":"Te\u0027sT\u0022t","times_selected":"1","id":"31"},{"comment":"","times_selected":"1","id":"32"},{"comment":"","times_selected":"1","id":"33"}]`, which is still generating the syntax error described above. This is quite baffling.

Comment: JSONLint approves the string, so why does JSON.parse expect a ',' or '}'?

Comment: No idea, but if you replace ``\u`` with ``\\u`` it seems to work. It's a bit of a kludge but better than nothing.

Comment: How would I go about generating the `\\u`s?

Comment: ``echo preg_replace( preg_quote('/\u/'), '\\u', json_encode( $a, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT ) );``

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented that, and have no problem with single quotes. However, double quotes are still being a problem. When the json_encoded PHP goes into the javascript, the additional \ from the `preg_replace` vanishes

Comment: OK, by adding a zillion backslashes to the `preg_replace` I've got it to work. Will edit the answer and accept. Thank you again.